# cordova 7.0.1 iOS build fails

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap

We recently updated our project to use cordova 7.0.1, ios@4.4.0, android@6.2.3.

Everything is fine with android build, no problem at all.

But iOS application build is a bit challenging a lot of warnings occurs, and finally error, so xcode can't complete build and Build fails.

The error in Xcode is:

Showing All Errors Only
ld: library not found for -lPods-OurProjectName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the .xcodeproj and open the .xcworkspace